# How to draw a shape(polygon) with an image placed behind it in canvas. The shape should be on top

Tags: javascript, html, canvas

The question is: the trees drawn in canvas are appearing behind the image of the slope. I want the trees on top of the slope image.
How do I do that? I have tried placing the image code after the trees code but its still not appearing behind the trees.

This is the index.html file

```html
<!doctype HTML>
    <html lang="en">
    <head>
            <meta charset="utf-8">
            <title>Cable Car</title>
            <meta name="Description" content="Using Canvas">
            <meta name="robots" content="noindex">
            <script src="scripts/stackoverflow.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
            <header role="banner">
                <h1>Canvas and animation</h1>
                <hr>
            </header>

            <main>
            <article>
                <canvas id="canvas" width="650" height="350"></canvas>
            </article>
            </main>

    <footer role="contentinfo">
    <hr>
    <p><small>
    Copyright &copy;2016. All rights reserved</small>
    </p>
    </footer>
    </body>
    </html>
```

Below is the js(javascript) file

```js
window.onload = function(){         
    var cnv = document.getElementById('canvas');
    var ctx = cnv.getContext('2d');

    //drawing the snow filled slopes - an image
    var cnvslope = document.getElementById('canvas');
    var ctxslope = cnvslope.getContext('2d');

    //the slope image 
    var slope = new Image();
    slope.src = "images/slope11.png";
    slope.onload = function(){
        ctxslope.drawImage(slope,412,153,slope.width,slope.height);
    }

    var cnvTrees = document.getElementById('canvas');
    var ctxTrees = cnvTrees.getContext('2d');

    //drawing the trees - 2nd from extreme right
    ctxTrees.strokeStyle='green';
    ctxTrees.lineWidth='1';
    ctxTrees.beginPath();
    ctxTrees.fillStyle = 'green';
    ctxTrees.moveTo(450,200);
    ctxTrees.lineTo(485,235);
    ctxTrees.lineTo(415,235);
    ctxTrees.closePath();
    ctxTrees.fill();
    ctxTrees.stroke();

    //drawing the trees - 2nd from extreme right
    ctxTrees.strokeStyle='green';
    ctxTrees.lineWidth='1';
    ctxTrees.beginPath();
    ctxTrees.fillStyle = 'green';
    ctxTrees.moveTo(450,225);
    ctxTrees.lineTo(505,275);
    ctxTrees.lineTo(395,275);
    ctxTrees.closePath();
    ctxTrees.fill();
    ctxTrees.stroke();

    //drawing the trees - 2nd from extreme right
    ctxTrees.strokeStyle='green';
    ctxTrees.lineWidth='1';
    ctxTrees.beginPath();
    ctxTrees.fillStyle = 'green';
    ctxTrees.moveTo(450,260);
    ctxTrees.lineTo(530,340);
    ctxTrees.lineTo(370,340);
    ctxTrees.closePath();
    ctxTrees.fill();
    ctxTrees.stroke();

    //drawing the trees - small tree-1st from extreme right
    ctxTrees.strokeStyle='green';
    ctxTrees.lineWidth='1';
    ctxTrees.beginPath();
    ctxTrees.fillStyle = 'green';
    ctxTrees.moveTo(600,250);
    ctxTrees.lineTo(610,260);
    ctxTrees.lineTo(590,260);
    ctxTrees.closePath();
    ctxTrees.fill();
    ctxTrees.stroke();


    //drawing the trees - 1st from extreme left
    ctxTrees.strokeStyle='green';
    ctxTrees.lineWidth='1';
    ctxTrees.beginPath();
    ctxTrees.fillStyle = 'green';
    ctxTrees.moveTo(600,255);
    ctxTrees.lineTo(620,275);
    ctxTrees.lineTo(580,275);
    ctxTrees.closePath();
    ctxTrees.fill();
    ctxTrees.stroke();

    //drawing the trees - small tree- 1st from extreme right 
    ctxTrees.strokeStyle='green';
    ctxTrees.lineWidth='1';
    ctxTrees.beginPath();
    ctxTrees.fillStyle = 'green';
    ctxTrees.moveTo(600,265);
    ctxTrees.lineTo(635,300);
    ctxTrees.lineTo(565,300);
    ctxTrees.closePath();
    ctxTrees.fill();
    ctxTrees.stroke();

    //drawing the trees - small tree-1st from extreme right-4th 

    ctxTrees.strokeStyle='green';
    ctxTrees.lineWidth='1';
    ctxTrees.beginPath();
    ctxTrees.fillStyle = 'green';
    ctxTrees.moveTo(600,285);
    ctxTrees.lineTo(650,335);
    ctxTrees.lineTo(550,335);
    ctxTrees.closePath();
    ctxTrees.fill();
    ctxTrees.stroke();
}
```

Answer (score 2):

**Put your tree-drawing code inside the `slope.onload` function.**

Step-by-step breakdown of what's going on:

1. You make a request to the server, and tell your computer to draw the image on the canvas after the image loads.
2. You draw trees.
3. The image loads, the image is drawn over the trees.

Step-by-step of what *would* happen if the tree-drawing code was added to the image's `onload` function:

1. You make a request to the server, and tell your computer to wait for the image to load. When it loads...

   1. Draw the image.
   2. Draw the trees.
2. The image loads, and this happens:

   1. The image is drawn.
   2. The trees are drawn over the image.

Comment: No problem, happy to help!